# search result action methods in layout xml

Tags: layout

a question in two parts:
Firstly, for my own understanding, where are the setSortBy and setDefaultDirection methods for the search result blocks?  These are all available to set in the layout xml  (e.g. catalogsearch.xml)  but I am unable to locate the actual methods inside any of the search blocks like I can with the setListOrders() method.  Are these just examples of the magic methods approach to these set______ function calls?  If so where are these properties stemming from?

Secondly,  how does one set the sortBy to sort with two fields?  I am looking to sort by product type  "Grouped" then "Simple"  and then by another parameter - in my case manufacturer.

```
<reference name="search_result_list">
    <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>asc</param></action>
    <action method="setSortBy"><param>manufacturer</param></action>
</reference>
```

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these just examples of the magic methods

Yes. If you find `setSomething` as layout action, search the blocks and templates for `getSomething` to see where it is used: [`getSortBy`](http://tinyurl.com/q28a65g)

> how does one set the sortBy to sort with two fields

This is not possible out of the box, you would need to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar`, specifically the [`setCollection()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php#L233) method. Then, if `getCurrentOrder()` which is the value from your layout XML, returns an array, comma separated list or however you want to define it, apply the multiple sort order to the collection:

You can call `$collection->setOrder($field, $direction);` two times with different fields to order by both fields.

Comment: thanks for the reply fschmengler.  I had kind of reached the conclusion about doing it with the collection.